# Javascript: add onclick attribute DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I've tryed to add some listeners to an existing div element

```
        //Prepare div
        $(this.div).css("z-index","256");
        $(this.div).attr("onmouseover",this.myname+".resize();");
        $(this.div).attr("onmousedown",this.myname+".resize();");
        $(this.div).attr("onmouseout","if("+this.myname+".sized)"+ this.myname+".resize();");
```

but in IE and Chrome the Event just doesn't get fired while it still
gets added to the elements attributes.
Firefox works as expected.

Does someone know whats wrong with it?

Thanks

Comment: You should really be using jquery's own evenhandling (`.hover()`) rather than adding to the attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Do not set events as strings.
Instead, you should use jQuery's `bind` method:

```
var me = this;    //Inside the handlers, this is the element.

$(this.div).bind('mouseenter mousedown mouseleave',  function() { 
    me.resize(); 
});
```

Comment: @Mereep - Also you don't have to create 4 instances of jQuery in order to do this. Use *method chaining*.